# How to insert data using insertAll with column number reference in Big Query?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, terraform-provider-gcp

I am using the Streaming Insert function insertAll() to insert data into my Big Query table.

I am using a Map and List as shown in the Java code example in BQ Docs - [bq docs link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery)

```
Map<String, Object> row = new HashMap<>();
List<InsertAllRequest.RowToInsert> rowContent = new ArrayList<>();
```

The map `row` has data of each column of a row and after reading the whole row, I'm adding it to `rowContent`. Later I'm passing it to the `insertAll()` function which takes a iterable declared like this:

`Iterable<InsertAllRequest.RowToInsert> rows`

**NOW MY MAIN QUESTION IS HERE:**

I am adding each column of a row to the Map by referencing the BQ Column name like:

`row.put("columnName", value)`

Is there a way to use column numbers instead of names?

For ex:

```
row.put(0, value0)
row.put(1, value1)
row.put(2, value2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, it's not an orderedMap and I would say NO. However, you can cheat.

Use an array of ColumnName

```
// Init
String[] columnNames = new String[3];
columnNames[0] = "Column1";
columnNames[1] = "Column2";
columnNames[2] = "Column3";
```

Then, in your `put` do this

```
row.put(columnNames[0], value0)
row.put(columnNames[1], value1)
row.put(columnNames[2], value2)
```

You can even imagine to create your `columnNames` array dynamically by reading the table metadata before starting the streaming.

Comment: Yes, Thank You. This is exactly what I was thinking before and have implemented the same.